# Simplify if and else to a single line

Tags: bash

I want to know if it is possible to reduce this line to a single one

```
if [[ $(curl --silent --output /dev/null --write-out "%{http_code}" "https://httpbin.org/status/200") -ne 200 ]]; then
  exit 1
else
  exit 0
fi
```

If the status code of the request was different from 200, exit with error, if it was successfully, exit with 0

Comment: Why? I think it's already hard enough to read as is...

Comment: Because it need to be very short, I am running it on a Argo workflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are exiting in both branches, you might as well just do:

```
status=$( curl ... )
test "$status" -eq 200
```

These must be the last lines of the script.  If for some reason you have more code in the script that you want to ignore but not delete, just add an `exit`.  If you want, you can be explicit and write `exit $?` but it's not necessary, since `exit` with no argument is equivalent.

The script will exit with the status of the last executed command, so if `"$status"` is 200, the script exits 0.  If it is not 200, it will exit 1.  Note that this also generates a comprehensible error message if the curl is somehow munged and `status` is set to a non-integer value, while that error message is not visible if you use `[[`.

Comment: Can I reduce it to something like this `test $( curl ... ) -eq 200` ?

Comment: @Rodrigo Yes, that will work, but you should add quotes: `test "$( curl ... )" -eq 200`.  There is no field splitting on the RHS of an assignment, so `status=$( ... )` without quotes is safe, but in `test $( curl ... ) ...` the output of curl is subject to field splitting.

Answer (score 3):

Just put `;` in proper places.

```
if [[ $(curl --silent --output /dev/null --write-out "%{http_code}" "https://httpbin.org/status/200") -ne 200 ]]; then exit 1; else; exit 0; fi
```

You can also do this:

```
exit $(( $(curl --silent --output /dev/null --write-out "%{http_code}" "https://httpbin.org/status/200") != 200 ))
```

Walter, here you go :p

```
exit $(( $(curl --silent --output /dev/null --write-out "%{http_code}" "https://httpbin.org/status/200") == 200 ? 0 : 1 ))
```

Comment: Please avoid "double negative" , write (( $(echo 200) == 200 )) && echo "Yes" || echo "No" not (( $(echo 200) != 200 )) && echo "No" || echo "Yes".

Answer (score 2):

`curl` already has [defined exit codes](https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/returns) for many situations if you use `-f`.

> A lot of effort has gone into the project to make curl return a usable exit code when something goes wrong and it will always return 0 (zero) when the operation went as planned.

```
$ curl -f -s http://google.com >/dev/null ; echo $?
0
$ curl -f -s hoop://google.com >/dev/null; echo $?
1
$ curl -f -s http://test.invalid >/dev/null ; echo $?
6
$ curl -f -s http://google.com/invalid >/dev/null ; echo $?
22
```

---

To return modified codes (eg. 0 on a 404 as you suggest in a comment), you could do simple boolean manipulation:

```
$ echo $((
    $(curl -f -s -o /dev/null \
        -w '!(%{http_code}==404)' \
        https://httpbin.org/status/200)
  ))
1
$ echo $((
    $(curl -f -s -o /dev/null \
        -w '!(%{http_code}==404)' \
        https://httpbin.org/status/404)
  ))
0
$
```

(substitute `exit` for `echo`)

Comment: I want to match with a specific HTTP code, sometimes, I want exit code 0 with a HTTP 404

Comment: @KamilCuk you still need to process the `!=` somehow.  my example code gives a framework for  more complicated logic (eg. "200 or 301 or 302", say) just by adding suitable clauses

Comment: @KamilCuk although you might still have to rewrite as say `exit $(( c=$(curl ...-w '%{http_code}' ...), ! (c==200||c==301||c==302) ))` - I keep the `!(...)` to separate the negation needed for `exit` from the actual logic

Comment: If you simply make the curl the last command in the script, there's no need for the `exit` and the `$(())` cruft.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```bash
[[ $(curl --silent --output /dev/null --write-out "%{http_code}" "https://httpbin.org/status/200") -ne 200 ]] && exit 1 || exit 0
```